# Why does $11! - 10!$ equal $10!$ plus an extra digit in "ones"?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Pardon my English as I'm not a native speaker of the language and I'm not a big math guy, so please bear with me and my ignorance for a bit. I've unconsciously stumbled upon something that's most probably blatantly obvious and easy, yet I have no idea how to explain it. So here it goes:

$$11! = 39916800$$
$$10! = 3628800$$
$$11! - 10! = 39916800 - 3628800 = 36288000$$

As you can see, the result equals the value that $10!$ returns "plus" an extra digit added. Is this just a cool coincidence or is there any logic behind that I'm just not aware of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$11!-10!=11\times 10!-1\times10!=10\times10!$

"10 times an integer" means that we put an extra 0 after the last digit of the integer.

Comment: Just a note to OP: This approach is also applicable to $(10n+1)!-(10n)!$ for any positive integer $n$, but an extra factor of $n$ will be applied to the number.

Answer (score 3):

By definition of the factorial, we have $$11! - 10! = 11 \cdot 10! - 10! = (11 - 1) 10! = 10 \cdot 10!$$ Now, as you may remember, multiplying by $10$ (or whatever base you are in) has the effect of shifting all digits to the left and adding a zero at the right of your number. This perfectly explains your extra zero at the end.

You might try to come up with other examples, such as $101! - 100!$.